# Internally in PHP, does passing-by-reference to the 'use' operator in a closure offer worse performance?

Tags: php, performance, closures

As I've read throughout other posts, passing-by-reference to a function offers much worse performance than passing-by-value(which utilizes copy-on-write). Does this also apply when passing a variable through the 'use' operator in a closure?

For example:

```
$message = 'hello';

$greetings = function () use (&$message) {
    echo $message;
};

$huge_number = 100000000;

while ($huge_number > 0) {
    $greetings();
    $huge_number--;
}
```

Will this also incur the overhead associated with passing variables by-reference? If so, does that mean that internally PHP 're-captures' the local scope everytime the function is called?

Comment: Test it and find out.  Time both versions of the code using `microtime(true)`  You may have to run them in a loop so it takes more then a split second.  Further if you are not modifying the data, your comparing an apple to an orange, because instead of by-reference you would have to return the data and set it.  (Which is the reason for it)

Comment: When running *any* benchark on this, take in ind that you're measuring the loop foremost. The reference will only be bound once to the anonymous function, btw. It's not a real closure, and PHP does not capture anything from the current scope (other than `use` declarations).

Answer (score 2):

This really isn't an answer but an explanation:

> passing-by-reference to a function offers much worse performance than passing-by-value

This may be but it's not really the purpose of pass by reference.  The purpose is to update the original without returning data or making a copy of the data.

So to test this

```
$greetings = function () use (&$message) {
   echo $message;
};
```

VS

```
$greetings = function () use ($message) {
     echo $message;
};
```

Is not really fair as the first one is doing things the second one is not.  And there is no purpose (or point) to use Pass by Reference there.

A fair test would be this:

```
$message = "foo";

$greetings = function () use (&$message) {
   $message .= " bar";
};

$greetings();
//$message = "foo bar";
```

VS

```
$message = "foo";

$greetings = function() use ($message){
    return $message . " bar";
};

$message = $greetings();
//$message = "foo bar";
```

So to test just calling it without testing how it affects the data, doesn't do it justice.  In other words, the first pair of examples maybe Pass-by reference is slower.  But in the second pair is that still true, how about memory usage etc.

In any case you can time them like this:

```
$start = microtime(true);
//...some code to test
echo format_number((microtime(true) - $start), 2));
```

But you may have to do it in a loop to make it take enough time to measure.  And even then, it will depend in large part on what the data is you are passing.